# PreparedStatement in Java on a Fulltext MSSQL Table only takes 3 Arguments

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Strange behavior.

We have the MSSQL server 2008 R2.

Our Java Servlet is calling a PreparedStatement with the following join.

```
... inner join Containstable (fulltextTable, mycolumn, ?) as KeyTable on id = KeyTable.[KEY] ...
```

Where ? = needle

This works fine.

But when i add two more arguments to Containstable like this:

```
... inner join Containstable (fulltextTable, mycolumn, ?, ?, ?) as KeyTable on id = KeyTable.[KEY] ...
```

Where ? = needle (Search for), ? = LANGUAGE N'German' (Language), ? = 250 (Limit result to 250 rows)

I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 4 of CONTAINSTABLE function.
```

This works fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

Is this a Problem with the SQLServerDriver in Java?

Cheers
Per

Here is my Code - this works:

```
if (contains!=null && contains.length()!=0) {
    sql.append(" inner join Containstable( myFulltext, myColumn, ?) as KeyTable on id = KeyTable.[KEY]");

    elementTypes.add(Types.NVARCHAR);
    paramObject.add(contains);
    //elementTypes.add(Types.NVARCHAR);
    //paramObject.add("LANGUAGE N'German'");
    //elementTypes.add(Types.BIGINT);
    //paramObject.add(maxResults);              
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are setting the values into the prepared statement?

Comment: Please show the code that gives you this problem.

Comment: The order of the Parameters in the Prepared Statement is correct.

Comment: I'm not saying your order is wrong, but instead, possibly the type of param you are setting does not match what is expected.

Comment: if i do this:Containstable( myFulltext, myColumn, ?, LANGUAGE N'German', ?) and send maxResults as second param, i get the same error.

Comment: It is very likely that the 4Th Parameter really is the problem. What kind of datatype is it? NVARCHAR would be wrong. But even when its hardcoded it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is because the third 'parameter' to `CONTAINSTABLE` is not a normal, scalar parameter, it's a keyword (`LANGUAGE`) followed by a value.

Most likely JDBC is transforming `LANGUAGE N'German'` into `'LANGUAGE N''German'''` and the resulting SQL is this, which is also invalid in SSMS:

`...containstable(myTable, myColumn, 'needle', 'language N''German''', 250)`

But of course it should be this:

`...containstable(myTable, myColumn, 'needle', language N'German', 250)`

You can confirm this guess by using SQL Profiler to trace the SQL actually being sent to the server. As for a solution, I don't know if JDBC will accept this:

`...containstable(myTable, myColumn, ?, language ?, ?)`

If it doesn't, you may have to use dynamic SQL to build a complete SQL string to execute, something like this (my quotes may not be completely correct, but you should get the idea):

`set @sql = N'...containstable(myTable, myColumn, ''' + @search term + ''', language ''' + @language + ''', + cast(@rows as nvarchar(10)) + ')'`

Unfortunately TSQL syntax is very inconsistent about where parameters are allowed and not, and this appears to be one such case.

Comment: Thanks i tried ?, language N?, ? - but it didn't work either - java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'N'. I need the N as well.

Comment: You shouldn't need that N as that is simply an introducer to indicate the string literal is a nvarchar. As your using a parameter that introducer doesn't make sense.

Comment: I tried ?, language ?, ? - same Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 4 of CONTAINSTABLE function.

Comment: As I mentioned, have you used SQL Profiler to view the SQL actually being sent to the serve? That will probably give you a better idea of what's going on.